# Drag Racing - Tuning Guide

Tags: drag-racing

Can anybody explain the tuning screen for Drag Racing (the mobile game)? Please don't give a list of tuning settings for particular cars.

I'd appreciate a description of what the settings mean and why you would tune the settings.

Comment: I can't seem to find mention of any particular game named "Drag Racing." Are you talking about "Drag Racer," the iOS game? If so, the tag should be changed to reflect the proper title.

Comment: Nope.  Probably "Drag Racing" for Android.  It currently has about 10-50 million downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to [Drag Racing for Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.creativemobile.DragRacing&hl=en), created by Creative Mobile Games.

[The Dro](http://the-dro.com/entertainment/tuning-tutorial-for-android-drag-racing-game/) has an excellent tutorial about tuning.  In general, the tuning process is a process to optimize your car for a particular use, for example, maximum acceleration without burning the tires in the 1/4 mile to win against those pesky cars that beat you off the line.  The great thing about tuning is that a well-tuned car can be much faster than its original settings.  The bad thing about tuning is that a badly tuned car will perform worse than factory settings, leading you to a fair bit of frustration about the whole experience.  There is a lot of trial and error involved here, which is why you might see some people bragging about their tuning settings (or refusing to share them) if they work particularly well.