# How to tune cars in Drag Racing?

Tags: drag-racing

I'm playing drag racing in which I've purchased tuning of cars but I don't know what's the exact settings. Can anyone tell me what's the perfect settings for cars?

[image: Tunning settings]

[image: The setting wizard of Applicaton]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very generic question. Each car has different caracteristics, so different settings would apply for each car. Also different settings are used when racing 1/4 mile or 1/2 mile.

@Zoot's answer on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37862/drag-racing-tuning-guide) is very good to give a basic understanding on Tune settings. As stated, The Dro has an excellent [tunning tutorial](http://the-dro.com/entertainment/tuning-tutorial-for-android-drag-racing-game/). Get a look at it.

As I can see by the screenshot, you purchased tune for **BMW M3 E92**. Unfortunately I don't own this car on the game to give you my personal settings, but here are some tips extracted from *The Dro*'s site, but edited by me:

**1. Nitrous.**

Setting it to 100%-110% seems to have good results.

**2. Final Drive.**

> This will depend on your car and what kind of start you want.
> You can bring this setting down in order to red-line without
> peeling out during take-off.

Set it around 3.2-3.7 to begin with and then tweak it after you're done setting up the rest of the gears.

**3. 1st Gear and 2nd Gear.**

> Make sure to upgrade the tires and drop some of the weight on the
> car first, so your car is capable of gripping better during take-off.
>
> Another thing to take note of is that second gear should be a lower
> number than first gear, but not too much.

Example:  1st Gear set to around 3.4 while 2nd gear is set to around 2.8.
Note that you can test anytime and check how it's working for your car.

**4. 3rd Gear.**

> This one will affect two things; The first thing being whether or not
> you can hit Nitrous with enough grip to launch you forward without
> peeling out too much causing you to be left behind. The second thing
> you need to watch for is whether or not your android drag racing car
> is powerful enough to launch you to 4th Gear in an extremely short
> amount of time.

Try to set it to 1.7. Note that this setting may change lower or higher according to ypur car's power.

**5. 4th Gear.**

> Again, depending on what car you have will depend on which setting this gear will have.

This gear should be set a bit lower than the third gear, so set it around 0.3-0.5.

**6. 5th, 6th, and 7th Gears.**

> I’ve noticed that these upper gears will make the difference in the top speed your car reached during the race combined with the *Final Drive Setting*.
> I tweak the settings very minor. I’ll first save my best test race settings under the presets screen for whichever race I’m tuning for (1/4 Mile or ½ Mile). Once It’s saved, then I can slowly tweak my higher gears one at a time along with the Final Drive and see which changes pushes my car to a higher top speed. You’ll notice some gradual changes will make a very big difference on your race times.

Hard to give an exact number here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuanalty, no-one will be able to give you the (absolute) best data for car tuning.

Depending on the car, the race distance, the upgrades chosen, and your driving style, tuning optimisation will change dramatically

because of the number of changes you can make, the total combination of tuning setups and resulting race times is unfathomably big. luckily, some people have got what they believe to be the perfect setup and are kind enough to post the details online (a quick google search confirms this)

If you truly want to find the best setup, im afraid trail and error on your part is required

Good luck :)   oh... and if you do find the ultimate setup, be sure to post it XD