# Tuning Cars in Nitro Nation android

Tags: nitro-nation

I am very new to these drag racing games and I am curious about tuning cars. From tuning I mean adjusting gear ratios and final drive ratios. I don't know what they are for so can someone explain it to me? Would be a great help.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear_ratio). It doesn't have anything to do with games in general, I suppose. More something like engineering. Or if you mean the same game as [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72550/how-to-tune-cars-in-drag-racing?rq=1), take a look at the accepted answer below it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear_ratio). It doesn't have anything to do with games in general, I suppose. More something like engineering. Or if you mean the same game as [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72550/how-to-tune-cars-in-drag-racing?rq=1), take a look at the accepted answer below it